# Why does this log file exist? Why does it continue to grow?

Tags: windows-11, logfiles

I was cleaning out my computer yesterday because I realized I had no space. Turns out, there was a rogue log file that was about 515GB. It sits alone in `C:/temp` and it's called `mfxlib.log`. It grows at about 1MB per minute. It doesn't increase smoothly, it dumps a bunch of info every now and then at seemingly random intervals. It will grow with no programs open.
[image: Picture of the log file]

Here is some text from it:
[image: Text from the file]

I really know nothing about computers, so I have no idea. For some additional context, I know it was not there before these two things: with the help of a friend, I significantly upgraded several computer parts (CPU, GPU, motherboard, power supply) and I upgraded to Windows 11. Maybe it's one, both, or unrelated. Moreover, there is no such directory in my D drive; my D drive is empty (including hidden files). I cannot find mfx_scheduler_core_thread.cpp in running processes. If it is related to a virus, MalwareBytes cannot detect said virus.

My drivers are up to date. I have all accessory updates installed.

- CPU: 12th Gen Intel(R) Core i5-12400
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 6650 XT
- MB: MAG B660M Mortar (Wifi) DDR4
- C: PCIe SSD
- D: Toshiba DT01ACA100

I assume something is verbose and shouldn't be. If nobody says anything, my next course of action will be to take out my D drive and see how the logs change. If you need more information, please let me know in the comments.

Edit: I have onboard Intel graphics from my CPU. Because the log seems to be from Intel Media, I disabled and re-enabled the graphics (which were not in use). This caused the issue to go away for 5 days. It has resurfaced. This time, I have just disabled the device completely without turning it back on (again it's not in use, so no worries). Will update if problem persists.

Comment: Google says it may belong to this - https://github.com/Intel-Media-SDK/MediaSDK - I know nothing about it, though, sorry.

Comment: see also: ( https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/media-sdk/overview.html ) One note: it is not uncommon for the paths reported in logs and error reports to reference the path the developer had on their system. I don't know why, but have seen e.g. unreal engine logs report a baked in path. Also, a `.cpp` file is source code, which is not executable which, again, points to a baked-in path (the source tree on the dev machine)

Comment: You might try using the system internals process explorer and figure out what exe has a handle open to that file.  C:\Temp is a red-flag right out of the gate.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm not sure why but the mystery file has returned. Both Sysinternals and Windows Resource Monitor reveal that no handles are open to the file.

Comment: Then use the process monitor to watch that folder.  It will tell you what is accessing it.  Also, windows machines do no use a forward slash for paths (as in C:/temp).

Comment: A patchwork solution I found was to just disable my Intel onboard graphics with device manager.
It magically reappeared today :D
I'm not sure when the Intel graphics device was re-enabled, but it was.
When I went to delete it, Discord had an open handle to the file?! Still have no clue.